# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning when chaining dataframe operations and displaying in Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

MRE:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data for demonstration
data = {
    "a": ["a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a"],
    "date": ["01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", "04/01/2021", "05/01/2021", "06/01/2021", "07/01/2021", "08/01/2021"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# CELL 1
# Delete duplicates
print(df.duplicated().sum())
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df  # Displaying the dataframe. In a Jupyter-like environment, this will print the dataframe.

# CELL 2
# Filter out certain values from "a"
print(df["a"].value_counts())
df = df[df["a"].isin(["b"])]

# CELL 3
# Convert "date" to datetime
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], dayfirst=True)
```

When executing the above cells sequentially in a Jupyter Notebook, I get a SettingWithCopyWarning in Cell 3. Strangely, if I remove the `df` (display command) at the end of Cell 1, I don't receive the warning.

I understand that the warning is there to alert users of potential pitfalls when modifying data on views vs. copies, but I'm not sure why displaying the dataframe would trigger this warning. Can someone **explain the reason behind this behavior** and suggest a clean way to address it?

I'm using Windows 11, `VSCode`, and `Python 3.11.1`.

For anyone struggling to reproduce the warning, you can head to https://colab.research.google.com/ which and copy my MRE. It will display the bug:
[image]

Comment: No warning for me, which pandas version did you use?

Comment: I get this warning using Notebook, Pandas 2.1.1 and the cell layout as described. Also strange - if you change df to print(df) then no error message. Weird! Presumably some quirk of Jupyter as the cell 3 statement should not give a warning anyway.

Comment: I'm using `pandas==2.1.0`. Apologies for not including it in the initial post @mozway.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce with several pandas version

Comment: What jupyter environment are you using?

Comment: I included a reproducible ENVIRONMENT in my initial post. @mozway

Comment: I can reproduce your [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCXHj.png) with Google Colab!!! Your code works fine with python/ipython console. I suppose Jupyter Notebook or Google Colab modify something to get beautiful datatable (unlike `print` or `repr`)

Comment: Obviously the message disappears when you use `df.copy()` as the last line of CELL 1.

Comment: If you remove the display from CELL 1, but then add one in CELL 2 or CELL 4 (a new cell at the end), do you still get the warning? My guess is something behind the scenes changes when you actually display the results you are generating.

Comment: @Nick Yes I still get it if I remove the display from CELL 1 and add it in CELL 2.